# What is wrong with my date regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, date

```
var dateRegex = /\/Date\((\d+)\)\//g;    // [0-9] instead of \d does not help.
dateRegex.test("/Date(1286443710000)/"); // true
dateRegex.test("/Date(1286445750000)/"); // false
```

Both Chrome and Firefox JavaScript consoles confirm. What the hell, guys?

Edit: even simpler test case:

```
var dateRegex = /Date\(([0-9]+)\)/g;
dateRegex.test("Date(1286445750000)"); // true
dateRegex.test("Date(1286445750000)"); // false
dateRegex.test("Date(1286445750000)"); // true
dateRegex.test("Date(1286445750000)"); // false
dateRegex.test("Date(1286445750000)"); // true
```

This shows that it alternates true/false every time...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your case remove the `g` modifier from the end, for example:

```
var dateRegex = /\/Date\((\d+)\)\//;
dateRegex.test("Date(1286445750000)"); // true
dateRegex.test("Date(1286445750000)"); // true
dateRegex.test("Date(1286445750000)"); // true
dateRegex.test("Date(1286445750000)"); // true
dateRegex.test("Date(1286445750000)"); // true
```

It's a bug with the way regexes are implemented in ECMAScript 3, [there's a great post on the details here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/es3-regexes-broken).

Comment: A bad browser behavior that isn't microsoft's fault? What gives? =)

Comment: Still no plans to add lookbehind support, heh?

Comment: @NullUserException - I don't keep up with this portion of the spec really, some of the regex guys might...but that article is a few years old, though it's the same bug as the OPs seeing.  What's on the table for future specs *may* have changed, but nothing I've heard about at least.

Comment: I reached same conclusion that removing g solves it, but thanks @nick I didn't know about faulty implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The `/g` was causing problem. Following code works fine.

```
<div id="test"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var reg = /Date\(\d+\)/; //REGEX WITHOUT g
        var d="Date(1286445750000)";
        $(function(){
            var $d=$("div#test");
            for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
                if(reg.test(d)){
                    $d.html($d.html()+"<br/>Matched: ["+d+"]");
                }
                else{
                    $d.html($d.html()+"<br/>Not Matched: ["+d+"]");
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```