# JavaScript function return paradox

Tags: javascript, regex, function

I have such function:

```
function validateData( value, rule ){
    var re = new RegExp( rule, 'gi' );
    alert(re.test( value ));
    return re.test( value );
}
```

Alert shows me `true`, but when I call this function:

```
alert(validateData( value, regExp ));
```

alert shows me `false`. Why?

Comment: if you comment out the alert, what it returns? I think it has something to do with how `RegExp` is working (probably `lastIndex` property is already set after first call)

Comment: Alerts `true` twice here - http://jsfiddle.net/7kCdX/

Comment: It's a bug in the regex engine in ecmascript, when you call `test` on certain RegExp expressions you modify the RegExp object, so it works the first time, then not the next time etc. Common issue.

Comment: Funny - few console.log(re.test( value )); return true next bt one

Comment: @adeneo, is it some 'magic' modification, as i dont see any differences in console.log between .test cals ?

Comment: @Evgeniy - no magic -> **http://jsfiddle.net/7kCdX/1/**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891641/regex-test-only-works-every-other-time

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff: Try some regex that does not match the empty string.