# Why does the statement if ( !condition ) { console.log(condition) } display true

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a String method, which accepts a RegExp and a callback, then splits String by RegExp, and inserts callback's return in split array. In short, it would do something like this:

```
"a 1 b 2 c".method(/\d/, function ($1) { return $1 + 1; })
    => [a, 2, b, 3, c]
```

In case the String doesn't match the RegExp, it should return an array, like this:

```
"a b c d e".method(/\d/, function ($1) { return $1 + 1; })
    => ["a b c d e"]
```

I wrote this code, but it doesn't work as I thought:

```
String.prototype.preserveSplitReg = function(reg, func) {

    var rtn = [], 
        that = this.toString();
    if (!reg.test(that)) {
        console.log(reg, that, reg.test(that));
        return [that];
    }

    ...
}
```

The console.log should be called ONLY when the String doesn't match `reg`, right? But sometimes it logs `(reg, that, true)`. That troublesome String and `reg` were:

```
"See <url>http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/</url> for changed elements and attributes, as well as obsolete elements and"
/<url>.*?<\/url>/g
```

console logs true. I can't figure out why. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you replicate using this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/QN8MT/

Comment: theCoder: I'm not friendly with fiddle. modified your suggestion and it looks like working...

Comment: Felix: it's interesting. I've noticed subtle difference between \d and [0-9]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [due to a bug in Javascript RegEx engine (ECMAScript3)](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/es3-regexes-broken)

Basically a regex with the `g` modifier doesn't reset correctly, so multiple `test()` calls toggle between `true and false`.

- See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3827500/548225 for more details.

Comment: seems like I should use recursive function, not /g. thanks

Comment: Yes that will be better or else don't rely on test method use match may be.